# What is the effect of nilotinib on electrocardiogram QT interval in advanced Parkinson disease?

Tags: wo2013166295a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2013166295A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2013166295A1)

As a physician and also a patient with advanced Parkinson disease (PD), I recognized the originality and merit of Dr. Charbel Moussa's proposal to treat PD with nilotinib, or a similar tyrosine kinase inhibitor (TKI), by employing low-level cellular autophagy to clear out the accumulated toxic alpha-synuclein (ASN) protein which is the pathological cause of death in affected neurons.  Dr. Moussa published a paper in 2013 which related his theories regarding the therapeutic potential of TKI's in PD and similar neurodegenerative diseases, and which documented dramatic reversal of PD in mice he treated with nilotinib. This paper was not his first on this topic, but it was the first time I was aware of his work and it convinced me that, if he could repeat those results in humans, he would be the first scientist to reverse the underlying course of PD in humans. This development, when fully proven in humans, will be one of the most significant advances in medical history and will certainly be awarded the Nobel prize in medicine. I would probably be taking nilotinib now, off label and self-prescribed based on Dr. Moussa's work, were it not for a rare but often fatal side-effect of nilotinib known as torsade de pointes (or just torsade), a cardiac arrhythmia that can strike suddenly and with little symptomatic warning.

Torsade, though, is predictably associated with a finding on the patient's electrocardiogram (ECG) called QT interval prolongation.  Drugs that increase the risk of torsade do so by prolonging the QT interval, in a dose-dependent manner.  Dr. Moussa addressed this concern by stating in his paper that the dose of nilotinib required to stimulate therapeutic autophagy in the brain of a PD patient would be substantially lower than the dose used to treat cancer patients, and that even at the full anti-cancer dose, torsade was a rare event.  However, PD is known to cause the loss of autonomic sympathetic innervation to the heart, which contributes to the dangerous drops in blood pressure in advanced PD.  Loss of sympathetic innervation might, in turn, result in the increased production of catecholamine receptors in denervated cardiac myocytes, thus potentially increasing their susceptibility to torsade, triggered by circulating catecholamines.

So, my specific question regarding patent WO2013166295A1 is this: what is the effect of nilotinib treatment on the QT interval (and thus, the likelihood of torsade) in PD patients treated with the reduced dose? The answer can be found by calculating the change in the QT interval in advanced PD patients treated with nilotinib.  This calculation consists simply of  subtracting the measured QT interval before administration of nilotinib from the measured QT interval during steady-state therapeutic dosing for each patient treated for advanced PD.  The larger this increase in the QT interval, the greater the increased risk of torsade.  Ideally, there would be no increase in the QT interval, but if so, the patient can be monitored more carefully and treated with medications to reduce the risk of torsade, such supplemental magnesium, potassium and beta-blockers if indicated.

Thank you for the opportunity to post this question, and I wish much continued success to Dr. Moussa and his research group at Georgetown University.